Does anyone know how to preserve class attributes in Lexical?
I'm working with Facebook's Lexical editor in Typescript and need to preserve class attributes on text nodes fx. on a h4 tag, when importing them to the editor through the $generateHtmlFromNodes method. I need the classes to persist in the editor, so that I can manipulate the html string after exporting it from the Lexical editor, but I'm a bit confused about the implementation of the importDOM method especially on what to return and how to make it preserve attributes. Can anyone help create a simple class that extends the TextNode class to allow for preserving the class attribute?
I understand that I need to update the importDOM & exportDOM methods, but everything I have tried does not seem to work...
Any help is greatly appreciated!!
Current implementation:
This is what I've been able to implement with the importDOM method, which I'm having trouble understanding what it should return and how I can manipulate it to preserve the classes on import (So sorry if it seems weird, but I've been trying different stuff without luck):
import {
  TextNode,
  EditorConfig,
  LexicalEditor,
  DOMExportOutput,
  DOMConversionMap,
  DOMConversionOutput,
  NodeKey
} from "lexical"

export class ClassNode extends TextNode {
  private tagName: string
  private __class: string
  /**
   * Constructor for creating an instance of ClassNode.
   * @param {string} classAttribute - The class attribute for the node.
   */
  constructor(tagName: string, classAttribute: string, text?: string, key?: NodeKey) {
    super(text || "", key)
    this.tagName = tagName
    this.__class = classAttribute
  }

  static getType(): string {
    return "class-node"
  }

  static convertClassNodeElement(domNode: HTMLElement): DOMConversionOutput | null {
    const hasClass = domNode.classList.length > 0

    if (!hasClass) return null

    console.log("domNode: ", domNode)

    return {node: new ClassNode("h4", domNode.className)}
  }

  /**
   * Clones an instance of CustomNode.
   * @param {CustomNode} node - The node instance to clone.
   * @returns {CustomNode} The cloned node instance.
   */
  static clone(node: ClassNode): ClassNode {
    return new ClassNode(node.tagName, node.__class, node.__text, node.__key)
  }

  /**
   * Creates the DOM representation of the node.
   * @param {Object} config - Configuration object passed by the editor.
   * @returns {HTMLElement} The DOM element representing this node.
   */
  createDOM(config: EditorConfig): HTMLElement {
    const element = document.createElement(this.tagName)
    element.className = this.__class
    return element
  }

  /**
   * Updates the DOM when the node has changed.
   * @returns {boolean} True if the DOM should be updated, false otherwise.
   */
  updateDOM() {
    return false
  }

  static importDOM(): DOMConversionMap | null {
    return {
      h4: (domNode: HTMLElement) => {
        return {
          conversion: ClassNode.convertClassNodeElement,
          priority: 4
        }
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Defines how the node is exported to an external DOM.
   * @returns {Object} The export configuration for the node.
   */
  exportDOM(editor: LexicalEditor): DOMExportOutput {
    const element = document.createElement(this.tagName)
    element.className = this.__class
    return {element}
  }
}

